# AccuRev .acignore files being apparently, well, ignored

Tags: android, version-control, ignore, accurev

I'm trying to set up a basic `.acignore` file for Android projects. Unfortunately, it seems AccuRev appears to be ignoring the contents of that .acignore file.

I've placed the following:

```
.gitignore
.git/*    
/*/local.properties
/*/out
/*/*/build
/*/*/production
*.iws
*~
*.swp
workspace.xml
tasks.xml
.gradle/*
```

Into an `.acignore` file in `PROJECT_FOLDER`, as apparently `.acignore` files only apply to the folder in which they are located (i.e., not recursively.) Executing `accurev stat -x` results in a flood of files of the form:

```
./PROJECT_FOLDER/.gradle/stuff1
./PROJECT_FOLDER/.git/stuff2
./PROJECT_FOLDER/PROJECT_NAME/build/stuff3
./PROJECT_FOLDER/.idea/etc
```

In short, most of my rules are not working. What have I done wrong? FWIW, I'm running AccuRev 5.5.0d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add/change the following entries in your .acignore file.

.git*

.gradle

PROJECT_NAME

.idea

This will resolve your files from appearing when running a stat -x.

Comment: This seems to work, although the reason for this is not explained. I extrapolate that the "/" character causes the rule to be ignored for some reason. So, I've had to place .acignore files inside any folder that contains a folder I want to ignore, which is a pain, but does the trick.

Comment: Once you upgrade to version 6, you only need to have the .acignore file located in the root level of your workspace.

Answer (score 4):

In AccuRev version 5.5, .acignore files apply to the directory in which they reside. Furthermore, recursive rules are not usable and will yield unpredictable results.

In version 5.7 and later, recursive rules are supported and a single .acignore file within the workspace top directory will apply to all directories below it.